# What are all the themes in the finale of Mozart's symphony 41?

Tags: notation, classical-music, fugue, mozart

I'm interested in learning more about the finale to Mozart's 41st symphony. I understand that there is a fugue with five themes, and that each of these themes are played at different times in the finale, as well as being played in counterpoint.

I wanted to know if anyone could produce a score for each of the five melodies, so that I could play them on the piano. I already know one of them: the four-note motif, C D F E. But I would like to learn the other motifs. Could anyone post a graphic with the notes to the other themes?

Here is the symphony. The 4th movement starts at 23:53.

Comment: Wikipedia answers the question: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symphony_No._41_(Mozart)

Comment: I saw that graphic. I don't think it gives instruments, though? Also, I wasn't sure if that provides all the notes for each theme. I feel like some are longer. Also, I was wondering if someone might transcribe the notes.

Comment: You can find the score in http://imslp.org/. I wouldn't expect anybody here is going to spend their own time going through the movement bar by bar, to do all the work for you! And specifically asking if someone can "transcribe the notes" is off-topic for this site anyway.

Comment: Something about this question seems fishy to me...

Comment: @Richard Why is it so? What is strange?

Comment: With all due respect to the OP, I just don't understand how s/he wasn't able to get this information on his/her own. No matter how I phrase my Internet search, the top result is *always* the IMSLP score to the symphony. And sometimes I get paranoid about the fear of someone asking a homework question; it's odd to me that the OP knows that this is "a fugue with five themes" but then asks for "a graphic with the notes." Something just doesn't add up. But maybe I'm just grumpy today! :-)

Comment: @Richard It's easy enough to learn that "this is a fugue with five themes" from the internet. But coupled with the OP's other question about Mozart symphony 1, I wonder if he/she can read staff notation. It's not a skill that most people are born with!

Comment: To be honest, I feel like you guys are ridiculing me. Is that the atmosphere of this forum, much like ELU? This was not a homework question, and I did see the graphic before asking, but I still had reason to doubt whether it was accurate or complete. It is NOT worth being paranoid about "homework questions" if that means making an honest questioner feel bad about himself. These are some basic values to live by, and I suppose you learn these values from reading books, not music.

Comment: Ktm - where a google search gives you the full answer, this site may not add anything. That's why the folks are trying to get to the bottom of your question. I would not assume they are trying to ridicule you.

Comment: @DrMayhem They are speculating that this is a homework question, for one. That, and four down votes, do not make me feel very welcome here. Nor is the tone of the comments very warm.

Comment: One person was speculating that. Another defended the question. I would imagine the downvotes are because Wikipedia already has a full answer for you. Some SE sites actually have a close reason of "not enough research" - what was your "reason to doubt "

Comment: @ktm5124 Just to clarify - this is not a forum or anything like it. It's a Q&A site which functions much more like an archive or database (this is how all SE sites work). As such, questions on these sites require some long term value for more than just the asker (as opposed to forums or Reddit). It is required that some initial research and effort be done by the asker. See [ask]. As for the downvotes, I suspect it's the usual case of an avalanche where you've gotten 1 or 2 and the rest followed. It happens, but there's no vote regulation (save fraud) so we have to live with that.

Answer (score 2):

How is [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symphony_No._41_(Mozart)#/media/File:Jupiter-fragment.png) not clear enough? If you compare instrument names, they are resp. from upper to lower: flutes, oboes, bassoons (divided), horns in C, natural trumpets in C, timpani in C and G, and strings (violins I & II, violas, cellos divided).

Comment: Ladies and gentlemen, yesterday I had two upvotes, and today it seems two downvotes cancel them. Isn't it an etiquette to explain why my reply does not answer OP's question? It is not that 20 points that I care.

Comment: I love the snark! And yes, I agree that I appreciate when down voters leave a comment, especially if the question has previously received up votes. If your reason to down vote isn't agreed upon by everyone, then it's not clear. Lemme know why!!